# Open source file hosting/sharing in php

Tags: php, linux, open-source, file-upload, download

Do you recommend an open-source project in PHP as a file hosting/sharing solution?

The project should support the following:

1- Register a new user.

2- Enable the user to download/upload files (doc, images, programs, etc.).

3- Define limits on the traffic upload/download (per user).

4- Define limits on the storage capacity (per user).

5- Enable the user to share his/her files.

The preferred platform is Linux.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think should fit your needs http://www.opendocman.com/features/

hope this helps